# Four-digit quadruples

Tags: pattern

A friend gave me this riddle, stating that it would be easy for children but hard for grown-ups.

Any combination of four digits has an determined value. Here are some examples (note, the position of the example is of no relevance):

```
0000 = 4
0001 = 3
1111 = 0
1234 = 0
2266 = 2
4068 = 4
6666 = 4
6088 = 6
7654 = 1
8888 = 8
8901 = 4
9966 = 4
9998 = 5
```

You may ask for any other four-digit number and there is a determined value for it as well. What is the value-function based upon?

Comment: It was pretty easy for adults too :)

Comment: Right, but he didn't have a whole community that is puzzler-affine only waiting for such an easy bit ;)

Comment: that's very true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value is:

> How many circles appear within the numbers

Explanation:

> Each number corresponds with a value, and they are additive for the final value of the 4 digit string. 0, 6, and 9 map to 1. 8 maps to 2, everything else maps to 0. This value for each digit is the number of circles within the drawing of the digit

Comment: I was writing the same thing :) good job

Comment: That was even quicker than I'm allowed to accept answers! Edit: and also correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is

> The sum of each number circles

Explanation:

> 0 has 1 circle
>  
> 1 has no circles
>  
> 2 has no circles
>  
> 3 has no circles
>  
> 4 has no circles
>  
> 5 has no circles
>  
> 6 has 1 circle
>  
> 7 has no circles
>  
> 8 has 2 circles
>  
> 9 has 1 circle

so

> 0000 = 1+1+1+1 = 4
>  
> 8888 = 2+2+2+2 = 8