# What is the next number in this puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence

What is the relationship of this sequence and what is the answer for the last?

- 0001112359 = 4
- 1887145865 = 7
- 5528695874 = 6
- 0000085021 = 8
- 3247514251 = 0
- 5847962150 = ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for fixing up your question! Unfortunately it still looks like it's a duplicate, though, so I've marked it as one. Still,  fixing a question with copied content like this isn't too common, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence counts the number of circles in the number.

> 0001112359 has 4 circles, 3 in the zeros and 1 in the nine
>   1887145865 has 7  circles, 6 in the eights and 1 in the six
>   5528695874 has 6 circles, 4 in the eights and one each in the six and the nine
>   0000085021 has 8 circles, 6 in the zeros and 2 in the eight
>   3247514251 doesn't have any zeros

Therefore,

> 5847962150 = 5 with 1 circle in the zero, 1 in the nine, 1 in the six, and 2 in the eight

Comment: how in the world did you figure that out.

Comment: @overloading There were several similar questions on the site that definitely gave me a direction. See [Four-digit quadruples](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14550/four-digit-quadruples) and the questions that its a duplicate of.